# spring-boot-starter-amqp not able to send message to AMQP exchange using user credentials with only write permission

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, cloudamqp

I am trying to send message to RabbitMQ from a springboot application.
Dependencies used (springboot & amqp) :

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I can publish message to the exchange using user credentials with below access(read, write and **configure**):

[image: user with configure access]

but it fails when I use user without configure permission as below :

[image: user without configure access]

error received while calling `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, null, message);` :

```
CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'MyExchangeName' in vhost 'my_vHost' refused for user 'my_user', class-id=40, method-id=10
```

I think it is because Spring it trying to create exchange or check if exchange is present (using Admin API). If that's the case can we disable it using some property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove any `Exchange/Queue/Binding` `@Bean`s or set the `shouldDeclare` property to `false`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62316257Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62316257Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange("foo");
        exchange.setShouldDeclare(false);
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "", "bar");
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, there was an Echange bean left while cleaning up.
Thank you for the help :)